# Is there any pure CSS solution to make a div's relative size the same aspect to its parent?

Tags: html, css

Say I have an SVG code like this:

```css
#svgparent {width:90%}
```

```html
<div id="svgparent">
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <rect x="5" y="15" width="250" height="70" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <text  x="5" y="35"><tspan font-weight="bold" font-size="15">Auto resizing, relative location is fixed</tspan></text>
  <rect x="15" y="35" width="50" height="25" style="fill:#fcc;stroke-width:3;stroke:none" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Is there any way that I can use pure CSS to do this for HTML elements?

```css
#out {
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#in {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
<div id="in">Reszing not following as the SVG elements</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What kind of output you want?

Comment: If it is about resizing the font javascript will be required

Comment: resizing the inner part totally like the SVG's performance. @RevtiShah

Comment: @G-Cyr Any official documents for this (why CSS is not possible)?

Comment: @AGamePlayer it can be possible with CSS. But can you give me an exact image?

Comment: Just the code in my second code snippet. When you resize the out box, the font-size is not getting smaller.

Comment: It is not possible because CSS is not a programming languageto start with, font-size has also specifity you can read about, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size  and it has nothing to do with looking at the size of its parent. font-size + calc() and vw/vh/vmin/vmax value can resize the font from the screen size, that's the most you can do. SVG is treated as an image,